# jQuery $.getJSON : Passing arrays to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

I have javascript passing an array to PHP with:

```
         var mapIDArray = ["4f8d7684791635ec2e000000", "4f8cbc087916359181000000"];

         $.getJSON("rebound.php",
            { 
                'mapIDs[]' : mapIDArray
            },

            function(output){

                console.log(output);

            }
        );
```

In rebound.php, I try to read the passed array (var_dump, print_r, etc.), such as:

```
print_r($_GET['mapIDs[]']);
```

But no luck...

Comment: try `print_r($_GET['mapIDs']);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need add the `[]` to the name.

```
var mapIDArray = ["4f8d7684791635ec2e000000", "4f8cbc087916359181000000"];
$.getJSON("rebound.php",
{ 
   mapIDs: mapIDArray
},
function(output){
    console.log(output);
});
```

Then in your PHP: `$_GET['mapIDs']` will be an array.

Comment: Didn't work – PHP is still not returning anything (PHP error log says "undefined index" for mapIDs.

Comment: @jrbaldwinn: `print_r($_GET)` to see if anything is being sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be `print_r($_GET['mapIDs']);` on the server-side, and

```
var mapIDArray = ["4f8d7684791635ec2e000000", "4f8cbc087916359181000000"];
$.ajax("rebound.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
            { 
                'mapIDs[]' : mapIDArray[0],
                'mapIds[]' : mapIdArray[1],
            },
            traditional: true,
            success: function(output){

                console.log(output);

            }
        );
```

on the client side. The key issues being that first, PHP sees it an an array with name 'mapIDs', even though it was mapIDs[] as a GET parameter, and second, multiple fields need multiple entries.

Comment: You can't have 2 elements in one object with the same name.

Comment: You're (mostly) right. I could set `traditional: false`, as is the default, and `mapIDs[]: mapIDArray`.

Comment: You shouldn't have the `[]` in the name with `traditional: false`.

Comment: You forgot the `{}` around the object passed to `$.ajax`.